# "pip" is not recognized in GITHUB desktop

Tags: python, git, github, github-for-windows, github-desktop

I have installed `git`, `github desktop`, `python 3.7.0` and 3.8.1 and have `py.exe` in my `c://windows` folder. Nevertheless, when I try to type a command in power shell in github desktop for a repo that I have cloned, it says that the "pip" is not recognized . Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Try to launch `where py` *(Windows)* / `which py` *(Linux, Mac)*.

Comment: Is `c:\windows` part of your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @OlvinRoght how to launch it?

Comment: @lonesome, type it in command line

Comment: @OlvinRoght says `cannot bind the parameter "filterscript"`

Comment: @lonesome, I have no idea what causes this message. Try to launch `cmd` and type `where py`.

Comment: @Mureinik That actually fixed the problem but a new problem has risen

Comment: @OlvinRoght can you take a look at my edit?

Comment: Don't move the goalposts. Roll back your change, accept the answer you got, and ask a new, better question.

Comment: @tripleee can you see an answer???

Comment: Can't you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63646920/874188

Comment: I edited my question1 hour ago and the answer is posted 27 min ago so I am right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executables are searched om your `PATH` environment variable, which probably doesn't include `c:\windows`. You need to edit this environment variable and add `c:\windows` to it.